# primality test for BigIntegers runs without stopping

Tags: java

Given a BigInteger, I want to test if is prime or not.

**Here is my class:**

```
public class Prime {

    public static boolean checkPrimality(BigInteger number) {

        if (number.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(3)) <= 0) {
            return number.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0;
        } else {
            if (number.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(2)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || number.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(3)).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        for (BigInteger i = BigInteger.valueOf(5); i.multiply(i).compareTo(number) < 0; i = i.add(BigInteger.valueOf(6))) {
            if (number.mod(i.add(BigInteger.valueOf(2))).equals(BigInteger.ZERO) || number.mod(i).equals(BigInteger.ZERO)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(checkPrimality(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(31).subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
        System.out.println(checkPrimality(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(60).subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
        System.out.println(checkPrimality(BigInteger.ONE.shiftLeft(61).subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    }
}
```

For the first 2 numbers, the output is **true** and **false** as expected, but for the third one (which is a prime number), the program runs without stopping.

Q: I want to know why the program does not stop, my guess is that there is some logic problem inside my method.

Comment: @khelwood I've followed the algorithm that I've found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Pseudocode

Comment: @jenniferlawrence Yeah, I get the idea. Could it be that your algorithm is just really slow? That is a big number you're trying to test.

Comment: @GhostCat I'm working with numbers larger than 20 digits

Comment: @jenniferlawrence have you used a debugger? I suspect it's not stopping simply because you are testing huge numbers: to get to 2^30, even in steps of 6, will take a very long time.

Comment: Then you should do some more research. When you have really large numbers, checking for prime needs to be done in different ways. See https://primes.utm.edu/curios/includes/primetest.php for some ideas.

Comment: And yes: dont write code that checks numbers, and **test** it for large numbers. Start with way smaller numbers ;-)

Comment: @AndyTurner I working for every number from [0, 60]. And the execution time is less than a second for each number, but when it comes to 61 is not working.

Comment: @GhostCat I know that there are better ways to do it, but I was just curious why my approach is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try to estimate the run times.

Your first number is:

```
N_1 = 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647
Sqrt(N_1) = 46430.95...
Sqrt(N_1) / 6 = 7723.49...
```

so your loop has to run less than 8k times, which is not a lot. Your second number is divisible by three:

```
N_2 = 2^60 - 1 = 1152921504606846975
N_2 / 3 = 384307168202282325
```

so the loop is never even entered. For the third number, however

```
N_3 = 2^61 - 1 = 2305843009213693951
Sqrt(N_3) = 1518500249.99
Sqrt(N_3) / 6 = 253083374.998
Sqrt(N_3) / Sqrt(N_1) = 32768.007...
```

Not surprisingly, since N_3 is about 2^30 times bigger than N_1, the number of loop iterations needed is about 2^15 times bigger. So if the algorithm finishes in a second for N_1, we'd expect it to take about nine hours for N_3.